# Solving $x + \lfloor x \rfloor = 2013x\cdot\lfloor x \rfloor + 2013^{-1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Find all possible solutions of the form $x = m/n$ (with $m, n$ coprime) of the equation: $$x + \lfloor x \rfloor = 2013x\cdot\lfloor x \rfloor + 2013^{-1}$$
>   ($\lfloor x \rfloor$ is the integer part of $x$)

Before even starting I have problems with the notation. As far as I know $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is the *floor* of $x$, while the problem states it is its *integer part*. Since according to [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerPart.html) the two are equivalent when $x \ge 0$, I have to assume that $x$ is non-negative.

Apart from that I tried rearranging the equation with no success. I've never solved an equation like this so I am wandering in the dark.

Comment: If I'm not wrong the only positive solution is $1/2013$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $n = \lfloor x \rfloor$ and $r = x - \lfloor x \rfloor$. Then, $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $r \in [0,1)$ must satisfy:

$x+\lfloor x \rfloor = 2013x\lfloor x \rfloor + 2013^{-1}$

$(n+r)+n = 2013(n+r)n+2013^{-1}$

$2n+r = 2013n^2+2013nr+2013^{-1}$

$(1-2013n)r = 2013n^2-2n+2013^{-1}$

$r = \dfrac{2013n^2-2n+2013^{-1}}{1-2013n} = \dfrac{(2013n-1)^2}{2013(1-2013n)} = \dfrac{1-2013n}{2013} = \dfrac{1}{2013} - n$.

For each integer $n$, if the resulting value of $r$ is between $0$ and $1$, then $x = n+r$ is a solution.

Can you finish from here?

---

EDIT: Even easier, $0 = 2013x\lfloor x \rfloor - x - \lfloor x \rfloor + 2013^{-1} = 2013(x-2013^{-1})(\lfloor x \rfloor-2013^{-1})$.

Comment: Right, I got it. I had done the substitution like you but couldn't finalize it (I just didn't think that $r \in [0,1)$. Also, your second solution is brilliant!

Comment: That first method is more general, and applies to other problems like $x\lfloor x \rfloor = 28$.